# How to use subclasses of ZMQ sockets

Tags: pyzmq

I'd like to subclass the zmq.Socket class in order to automatically serialize Python objects before sending them and deserialize received messages. Now the docstring of zmq.Socket sais that in order to create a socket, I should create a *context* and then call

```
socket = context.socket(socket_type)
```

With this scheme, how can I use my own subclasses of zmq.Socket?

Answer (score 1):

There's a (sadly undocumented) `_socket_class` attribute on the zmq.Context class which can be used to customize the result of the `socket(socktype)` method. For example, to add [CBOR](http://cbor.io/) serialization methods:

```
import cbor
import zmq

class CBORSocket(zmq.Socket):
    def send_cbor(self, obj, flags=0):
        return self.send(cbor.dumps(obj), flags=flags)

    def recv_cbor(self, flags=0):
        return cbor.loads(self.recv(flags=flags))

class CBORContext(zmq.Context):
    _socket_class = CBORSocket

def main():
    ctx = CBORContext()
    rep = ctx.socket(zmq.REP)
    req = ctx.socket(zmq.REQ)
    rep.bind('inproc://foo')
    req.connect('inproc://foo')
    req.send_cbor('Hello world!')
    print(rep.recv_cbor())

main()
```

Despite the lack of documentation for `_socket_class`, it does appear in one of the pyzmq [example scripts](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/serialization/serialsocket.py) although these don't appear to be used in the [documentation itself](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Still, I'm hoping that means it's official / unlikely to disappear arbitrarily!

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the `send_pyobj` and `recv_pyobj` methods in socket? They serialise Python objects with pickle.

Does this solve your issue? Otherwise it would be great if you could specify your question.

Comment: No, this doesn't solve my problem. I already have my own serialization functions, and I have added them to my custom subclass of ZMQ sockets. My question is: How can I make ZMQ use my custom subclass of zmq.Socket?